Dynamic parallel stages for declarative pipeline based on job input parameters
I'm trying to set up some dynamically parallel Jenkins pipelines based on list input parameters, but I can't find anything in the documentation and I'm wondering if folks here have figured out ways to do this.
As an example, what I'm trying to do could be something like:
@Library([...]) _
properties([]
  + string(name:'VARIANTS', defaultValue:'varA', description:'Comma-delimited list of variants to build.'),
  ...
)

pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    ...
  }
  stages {
    stage('Execute all variants in parallel') {
      /**
       * 1. Parse the `VARIANTS` input into a list of strings
       * 2. Execute, in parallel, a build for each variant from the list
       * */
    }
  }
}

As far as I can tell, the parallel won't work for this, so my instinct would be to use matrix, but my research indicates that matrices don't support these sorts of lists. Any tips or tricks for this sort of behaviour?


As far as I can tell, the parallel won't work for this...

The parallel step will work if you provide a map of closures mapped by a string which will be stage names while executing the closures in parallel:
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name:'VARIANTS', defaultValue:'varA, varB', description:'Comma-delimited list of variants to build.')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Execute all variants in parallel') {
            steps {
                // We need to escape the declarative pipeline syntax to execute a scripted block
                script {
                    // Split the comma-delimited list of variants into a list of strings
                    List<String> selectedVariants = params.VARIANTS.split(',').collect { it.trim() }
                    // Create a map of stages to execute in parallel
                    Map<String, Closure> stages = selectedVariants.collectEntries { variant ->
                        ["Building: $variant": {
                            // Execute the stage for the selected variant
                            echo "Making ${variant}..."
                            // Add your build steps here
                        }]
                    }
                    // Execute the stages in parallel
                    parallel stages
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Then for the input: varA, varB, varC

You will get the desired outcome

